# Issue with "ModuleNotFoundError" when running scripts in Docker Image

Tags: python, docker

I have a set of scripts that I'm trying to run in a Docker Container. All the packages seem to be "found" when I'm writing my code in PyCharm. But when I run it in my Docker container it gives me an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named engine"

The directory structure of my scripts on my computer is

```
C:\Users\alex\Documents\Work\DataIntegration\engine
```

inside of `engine` I have

```
/py_core # "package" with helper scripts. Contains __init__.py
DockerFile
__init__.py
main.py
```

My code starts from `main.py` and fails on the first import statement when it tries to get a function from a file in `py_core`.

My Docker file is pretty simple

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.6

# indicating the files that need to be added to the new image:
COPY . /

# install the Python application's dependencies from requirements.txt:
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# instructs Docker to start our Python service when the image is run:
CMD [ "python3.6", "-u", "main.py" ]
```

The way I build and run my docker image.
I use Docker toolbox because I've had a lot of trouble with Docker desktop.

On CLI I navigate to the `engine` directory on my computer and run the following:

```
docker build -t myproject .
```

To run my project

```
docker run myproject
```

This is supposed to run through the scripts process but it fails on the first import.

I've seen some info online about the `__init__.py` files and I've put one in pretty much every directory I have in this project and it still gives me the 'module not found error'. I've seen some info as well on using the PYTHONPATH but I'm not sure at all what I need to set my PYTHONPATH to resolve this issue.

Any help appreciated thanks

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: try `COPY . .` instead of `COPY . /`

Comment: Your contents of `main.py` & the full error.